# Getting the first instance of an item in an array

Tags: php

```
$string = array('A','B','C','A','B','C');
```

For example first instance of C in $string would be 2

Is there a simpler way to do this than doing a complex loop in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_search()` function. (http://php.net/array_search)

Answer (score 1):

Array_search() will do exactly what you want.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php